# Matrix multiplication very slow in Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, optimization, eigen

I have implemented a Gauss-Newton optimization process which involves calculating the increment by solving a linearized system `Hx = b`. The `H` matrx is calculated by `H = J.transpose() * W * J` and `b` is calculated from `b = J.transpose() * (W * e)` where `e` is the error vector. Jacobian here is a n-by-6 matrix where n is in thousands and stays unchanged across iterations and `W` is a n-by-n diagonal weight matrix which will change across iterations (some diagonal elements will be set to zero). However I encountered a speed issue.

When I do not add the weight matrix `W`, namely `H = J.transpose()*J` and `b = J.transpose()*e`, my Gauss-Newton process can run very fast in 0.02 sec for 30 iterations. However when I add the `W` matrix which is defined outside the iteration loop, it becomes so slow (0.3~0.7 sec for 30 iterations) and I don't understand if it is my coding problem or it normally takes this long.

Everything here are Eigen matrices and vectors.

I defined my `W` matrix using `.asDiagonal()` function in Eigen library from a vector of inverse variances. then just used it in the calculation for `H` ad `b`. Then it gets very slow. I wish to get some hints about the potential reasons for this huge slowdown.

EDIT:

There are only two matrices. Jacobian is definitely dense. Weight matrix is generated from a vector by the function `vec.asDiagonal()` which comes from the dense library so I assume it is also dense.

The code is really simple and the only difference that's causing the time change is the addition of the weight matrix. Here is a code snippet:

```
for (int iter=0; iter<max_iter; ++iter) {
    // obtain error vector
    error = ...  
    // calculate H and b - the fast one
    Eigen::MatrixXf H = J.transpose() * J;
    Eigen::VectorXf b = J.transpose() * error;
    // calculate H and b - the slow one
    Eigen::MatrixXf H = J.transpose() * weight_ * J;
    Eigen::VectorXf b = J.transpose() * (weight_ * error);
    // obtain delta and update state
    del = H.ldlt().solve(b);
    T <- T(del)   // this is pseudo code, meaning update T with del
}
```

It is in a function in a class, and weight matrix now for debug purposes is defined as a class variable that can be accessed by the function and is defined before the function is called.

Comment: `T <- T(del)`??

Comment: @erip use del to update T

Comment: You've determined (benchmarked) that the calculation of `U` and `b` are the bottlenecks and not `solve`?

Comment: Might be an overloaded operator, but that seems suspicious... Suspiciously like `T < -T(del)`, or, `T` less than `-T(del)`.

Comment: @erip This is a line of pseudo code, I made an edit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you have an MCVE for this

Comment: @AviGinsburg That is a good thought, but I am basically multiplying an identity W matrix now. H is only 6-by-6 so solve shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `weight_` is declared as a dense `MatrixXf`? If so, then replace it by `w.asDiagonal()` everywhere you use `weight_`, or make the later an alias to the `asDiagonal` expression:

```
auto weight = w.asDiagonal();
```

This way Eigen will knows that `weight` is a diagonal matrix and computations will be optimized as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Because the matrix multiplication is just the diagonal, you can change it to use coefficient wise multiplication like so:

```
MatrixXd m;
VectorXd w;
w.setLinSpaced(5, 2, 6);

m.setOnes(5,5);

std::cout << (m.array().rowwise() * w.array().transpose()).matrix() << "\n";
```

Likewise, the matrix vector product can be written as:

```
(w.array() * error.array()).matrix()
```

This avoids the zero elements in the matrix. Without an MCVE for me to base this on, YMMV...